# Custom authorization attribute in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm building an API in .NET Core 1.1. I build a custom `User` object from `HttpContext.User` in a base controller that all of my other controllers inherit from, and I have authentication enabled by default (must be manually disabled with `[AllowAnonymous]` when necessary). The `User` object has an `IsAdmin` property. Right now I'm checking if the user is an admin at the top of each relevant function like below, but I feel like there must be a way to add a custom attribute to simplify and clean up this code.

For reference, `User.IsAdmin` is shorthand for this:

```
bool.Parse(HttpContext.User.FindFirst("IsAdmin")?.Value)
```

Instead of this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    if (!User.IsAdmin)
        return Forbid();

    // logic
}
```

I'd like this (or something similar):

```
[AdminOnly]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
    // logic
}
```

I tried looking at the [source for `[AuthorizeAttribute]`](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization/AuthorizeAttribute.cs) to try to build from, but it's just a shell and I don't know where the real magic happens.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I suggest read the docs about policy based authorization, you basically use an attribute with a named policy then you define the policy in startup to require some role or claim or other rule https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies

Comment: Check the answer from @blowdart (responsible for ASP.NET Core security), you shouldn't (or have the need) create your own attributes

Comment: @JoeAudette Looks like that's what I need, not sure how I missed it. :/ [Claims-based auth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims#adding-claims-checks) will work, as I only need to verify that the claim is `true`. If you add that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 9):

The solution suggested by @JoeAudette seems to be the best option.

Create your own policy in `Startup.cs` ConfigureServices():

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => 
    options.AddPolicy("PolicyName", p =>
    {
        p.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        p.RequireClaim("IsAdmin", true); <- your criteria here (claim type, claim value) ???
        p.Build();
    })
);
```

Then just use it as an attribute:

```
[Authorize("PolicyName")]
```